# Searching for a keyword in a string, in an NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray

I've got an **array of keywords** and an **array of strings**.

I'm currently iterating out the keywords and using a filter on the strings array to determine whether or not the keyword is in there (in some form).

The below code works, however when there is a keyword (or the same characters as the keyword) within another word, this is flagged. ie. Searching for *bon* in string *ribbon* would flag ribbon. I don't want to do an exact comparison as it's possible the keyword will be surrounded by other characters / words in the string.

**Is there a way I can search for it and only flag it if it's surrounded by whitespace or brackets? ie. Not part of another word..**

```
NSArray *paInc = [productIncludes valueForKey:pa];
// This is the array of keywords

NSMutableArray *paMatchedIncludes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (id include in paInc){

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [cd] %@", include];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [stringArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    // stringArray is the array containing the strings I want to search for these keywords

    for (NSString *ing in filteredArray){
        if ([ing length] > 0){
            if (![paMatchedIncludes containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ing]]){
                [paMatchedIncludes addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ing]];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following code solve your problem?

```
NSArray *paInc = @[@"bon",
                   @"ssib"];
// This is the array of keywords

NSArray *stringArray = @[@"Searching for bon in string ribbon would flag ribbon.",
                         @"I don't want to do an exact comparison as it's possible the keyword will be surrounded by other characters / words in the string."];
// stringArray is the array containing the strings I want to search for these keywords

NSMutableArray *paMatchedIncludes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (id include in paInc){ // for every keyword
    for (NSString *nextString in stringArray) { // for every string
        NSArray *components = [nextString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" ()"]];
        if ([components containsObject:include]) {
            [paMatchedIncludes addObject:nextString];
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT (due to your comment): For case insensitive compares:

```
for (id include in paInc){ // for every keyword
    for (NSString *nextString in stringArray) { // for every string
        NSArray *components = [nextString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" ()"]];
        for (NSString *nextComponent in components) {
            if([nextComponent caseInsensitiveCompare:include] == NSOrderedSame)
                [paMatchedIncludes addObject:nextString];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did solve part of the issue. The keyword case and the string case may not always be the same. Is there a way to account for mismatch case?

Answer (score 0):

I guess [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is what you want.